# How to find the list of available users using asp.net and SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 table called `users` which stores users details. I have an aspx page that users will be redirected after they logged in.

How might I find the list of user with their user details who are currently logged in without any updating this table? Do I need need a separate table to maintain login history?

Some one suggest me to use ASp.net Membership and roles functionality. By using this how could I able to find the list of logged in users? i.e, online users and offline users?

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408762/check-facebook-login-status-and-get-session-details-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk

Comment: And also refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833786/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-already-logged-in-or-not-using-cookie

Comment: @Fernando What's that link got to do with this question?

Comment: The above link is how to find log-in status of user. But i need the list of users whoever logged in.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you need to do in the SQL server side - the most common approach is to use the Session object and write code in the `Session_Start` and `Session_End` events of Global.asax.

The answer to this question will be a good starting point for you: [asp.net visitors count (online users) for today-yesterday in .net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960501/asp-net-visitors-count-online-users-for-today-yesterday-in-net-4)

**EDIT:** To add to this following your comment, to do that I'd suggest using the SQL Server Membership Provider and deriving a list of users from the session IDs.

If you wanted to do this with your own (custom) users/login schema then you'd need to add a column to write the session ID in every time they logged in, then remove it when the session expired, again making use of the `Session_Start` and `Session_End` events.

But I'd strongly recommned you use the .NET Membership as you could end up introducing security holes by rolling-your-own as it were.

Comment: Fine. But it gives only the count and it doesn't get user details which stored in database i.e, i need list of users with their username

Comment: I've added some more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Widor, but If you HAVE to do it on SQL and you users are SQL Server Users, you can run `exec sp_who2` to get a list of active users.

edit:

```
select distinct(loginame)
from master..sysprocesses 
where db_name(dbid) = 'DB_NAME'
```

Comment: sorry i need the users whoever logged in my webpage whose user details are stored in sqlserver and not only on sql.

Comment: ok, try running the query I wrote, it will bring a list of SQL Server users. Now what you have to do is join it with your user table and you get the info you need

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one column with your datatable as flag, set true  once login and set false on Session_End event.

get list base on flag column (e.g.) where flg=true